# "It is just one way" -- ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, lyrics

I wonder what the following fragment of lyrics of the song *"Ticket To The Moon"* by *Electric Light Orchestra* means:

> Ticket to the moon
>
> Flight leaves here today from Satellite Two
>   As the minutes go by, what should I do?
>   I paid the fare, what more can I say?
>   It's just one way (only one way)...

I suppose it may mean either *it is the only right solution* or *one cannot come back from moon", is it right?

P. S. English is a foreign language for me, so you're welcome to correct this question if something is wrong.

Comment: That's confusing to me too. I'd go with **It's a one way trip**. Plus, it's a song, so there may be two meanings at the same time.

Comment: Is there any reason to object that the lyrics of a song are ambiguous??  Ambiguity is one of the beauties of the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question, because a) "it's just one way" is indeed ambiguous, but b) in an entirely different manner from the one you've outlined.

It can mean either of the following:

1. the ticket is one-way
2. it is but one way out of several possible ways

However, you cannot use "it's just one way" in order to convey the other meaning you have in mind:

3. it is the only right solution

This is ungrammatical in English. Instead you would have to say either of the following:

- *there's* just one way
- it's *the only* way

If you mix them together, you get an ungrammatical result.

"It's just one way to skin a cat" is only grammatical in the meaning 2 above, "this here is merely one out of several approaches to skinning a cat". Using it in the meaning 3 firmly puts you in non-native speaker territory.

Comment: And applying this to the lyrics at hand, we get: meaning 3 is impossible; meaning 2 is a theoretical possibility, but extremely unlikely; meaning 1 is quite clearly the intended one. However, lyrics interpretation is off-topic here, so I'm only leaving it as a comment.

Comment: There is no reason the lyrics cannot be interpreted to mean "one cannot come back".